# having correct naming of directories

Tags: javascript, node.js, visual-studio, powershell, bcrypt

**this is shorted error logs :**

> npm ERR! code 1
> npm ERR! path

```
C:\Users\Sam Taklimi\Desktop\D&D\ChatApp-Rooms\node_modules\bcrypt
```

> npm ERR! command
> failed npm ERR! command C:\WINDOWS\system32\cmd.exe /d /s /c
> node-pre-gyp install --fallback-to-build npm ERR!
> 'D\ChatApp-Rooms\node_modules.bin' is not recognized as an internal
> or external command, npm ERR! operable program or batch file. npm ERR!
> node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:936 npm ERR!   throw err;

Comment: What exact command did you run?

Comment: i have checked if i have python and other module with -v so they are installed ,,, but still cant find them
 
im using this command :
`npm install --g --production windows-build-tools`

Answer (score 0):

Finally I find my problem !
I had a directory which I named it D&D :

```
C:\Users\Sam Taklimi\Desktop\D&D\ChatApp-Rooms
```

the

```
 &
```

should not be part of directory name , I removed it and now fixed .